# How to send a welcome message in server using discord.py in a server

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I would like my bot to send a msg when someone joins the server (also mention them)

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print('welcome!'f'{member}')
```

the only thing i want to change is this should be displayed in the general channel (its printing it in the terminal now) and that instead of only displaying the person's name i want it to mention them.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

to send a message to a channel you need to get the channel and then send the message to there, you can get the channel using [get_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Client.get_channel)

```py
client.get_channel(1234567890)# change to your channel id
```

or using [discord.utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20utils%20get#discord.utils.get) incase you want to use name instead

```py
discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name="welcome")
```

and for mention, discord.py has provided us with [member.mention](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20mention#discord.Member.mention)

```py
await channel.send(member.mention)
```

and combining both things we can make this

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(1234567890) # change to your channel id
    await channel.send(f"Welcome {member.mention}!")
    print(f'{member.name} joined the server')
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out but i got an error again T_T
From what i understood this is what i did: 
`@client.event      
async def on_member_join(member):      
    channel = client.get_channel(737933993340698664)     
    await channel.send(f'welcome {member.mention}')      
    print(f'welcome {member.mention}')`        
I did not get any errors but the bot did not print out any msg. Did i make a mistake?

Comment: did it send the welcome message send to the channel?

Comment: nope it didnt send any msg. Im sorry i forgot to add that in my prev comment. I did not get any error in my terminal

Comment: it's strange because the code worked for me and my friends. Are you sure it does not raise any error?

Comment: Make sure to enable intents

Comment: so this is my code [link] (https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/757291238847152219/784366790587056148/Screenshot_2020-12-04_at_4.03.10_PM.png) Have i done something wrong?
Yes it did not throw any errors, i only got my on_ready message in terminal

Comment: yes, you need to enable [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents)

Comment: [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/757291238847152219/784371898167197716/Screenshot_2020-12-04_at_4.23.27_PM.png) Theyre turned on.

Comment: you also need to tell the botlike this:
`intents = discord.intents.all()
client=commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)`

another link for intents so you can customize it
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents

Comment: It worked!!! :D 
THANK YOU VERY VERY VERY MUCH!!! im really grateful for your help!

Comment: nice to hear it